# How to return 0 incase of empty result in oracle select query?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a Query where there is number datatype column. In case of empty resultset O/P is blank. I want `0` in that case.

My query is

```
select nvl(infodata,0) 
from table1 
where group_id = 111 
  and appid in (select max(id) 
                from table1, table2 
                where status = 'A');
```

Now my inner query is returning null in that case. `NVL` seems to be not working on infodata column. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Outcome of such a query is *no rows selected*.

For example (based on Scott's `EMP` and `DEPT` tables as I don't have yours, and you didn't post test case), this query returns *nothing*:

```
SQL> select e.deptno
  2  from emp e
  3  where e.ename = 'Littlefoot';

no rows selected
```

If it is used as a subquery, the result is equal to what you currently have:

```
SQL> select nvl(d.dname, 'x') result
  2  from dept d
  3  where d.deptno in (select e.deptno
  4                     from emp e
  5                     where e.ename = 'Littlefoot'
  6                    );

no rows selected
```

But, if you apply aggregation (see line #1), then you'd get what you wanted:

```
SQL> select nvl(max(d.dname), 'x') result
  2  from dept d
  3  where d.deptno in (select e.deptno
  4                     from emp e
  5                     where e.ename = 'Littlefoot'
  6                    );

RESULT
--------------
x
```

---

As I said: it *works* on my test case; might, or might not on yours. If you post sample data, we'd have something to work with.